# Syntax error on update from select query

Tags: mysql

I keep getting a syntax error on line 3 in my `"FROM( SELECT"`. I can't seem to figure out what might be causing it.

```
UPDATE lab_orders_lab_confirmationresults_c t
SET lab_orders_confirmationresultslab_confirmationresults_ida = foo.`1ID`
FROM(
        SELECT x.id as '1ID', y.id as '2ID'
        FROM lab_orders x 
        INNER JOIN lab_confirmationresults y ON x.orderid = y.orderid
        )foo
WHERE t.lab_orders_confirmationresultslab_confirmationresults_ida = 'undefined'
AND t.lab_orders_confirmationresultslab_confirmationresults_idb = foo.`2ID`
```

Comment: SET FROM. That ain't gonna work. And 1ID??

Comment: You can't use `FROM` in `UPDATE` query, it's reserved for `SELECTs` and `DELETEs`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html

Comment: @divix You can't use the keyword, but you can use the concept.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE ... FROM ...` isn't valid syntax. The closest you could get is

```
UPDATE table
  SET a_column = 
    (SELECT one_column
      FROM another_table
      WHERE some_condition
      LIMIT 1)
```

Note that the `SELECT` ***must return exactly one row of one column width*** for this to work.